# LibreOffice. Getting OutOfMemoryException while execute Conversion to PDF not instantly, but after long time of work

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

We have service on .Net6, that convert documents from Docx to PDF format.
Service has been deployed on Linux container (k8s) and have LibreOffice binary within

LibreOffice has been installed inside container by script below

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        default-jre \
        libreoffice \
        libreoffice-writer \
        ure \
        libreoffice-java-common \
        libreoffice-core \
        libreoffice-common \
        fonts-opensymbol \
        hyphen-fr \
        hyphen-de \
        hyphen-en-us \
        hyphen-it \
        hyphen-ru \
        fonts-dejavu \
        fonts-dejavu-core \
        fonts-dejavu-extra \
        fonts-droid-fallback \
        fonts-dustin \
        fonts-f500 \
        fonts-fanwood \
        fonts-freefont-ttf \
        fonts-liberation \
        fonts-lmodern \
        fonts-lyx \
        fonts-sil-gentium \
        fonts-texgyre \
        fonts-tlwg-purisa

RUN apt-get -y -q remove libreoffice-gnome && \
    apt -y autoremove

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN adduser --home=/opt/libreoffice --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell=/bin/bash libreoffice
```

For converting documents we use invokes soffice via Process and pass arguments
List of arguments placed below:

```
        private List<string> GetCommandArguments(string docx, long userId, string tempFolder)
        {
            return new List<string>
            {
                "--convert-to",
                "pdf:writer_pdf_Export",
                docx,
                $"-env:UserInstallation=file:///{this.options.Value.TempUserPathForArgs}{userId}",
                "--norestore",
                "--writer",
                "--headless",
                "--outdir",
                tempFolder
            };
        }
```

This configuration works fine, but after some time (approximately after several hours depending on load) we get OutOfMemoryException when trying to invoke LibreOffice Process
P.S. Documents converting in Parallel by creating new session(creating temp user) for every process

First Error

```
Message: "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.",

StackTrace: at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(ThreadHandle t, Int32 stackSize, Int32 priority, Char* pThreadName)\n   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCore()\n   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WaitThread..ctor()\n   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.RegisterWaitHandle(RegisteredWaitHandle handle)\n   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(WaitHandle waitObject, WaitOrTimerCallback callBack, Object state, UInt32 millisecondsTimeOutInterval, Boolean executeOnlyOnce, Boolean flowExecutionContext)\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureWatchingForExit()\n   at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Gems.IO.LibreOffice.LibreOffice.ConvertToPdfInternalAsync(String docxPath, String pdfPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n
```

Second Error

```
An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/soffice' with working directory '/app'. Resource temporarily unavailable

LibreOffice has failed. Exit code: 2

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

How does it fix? What could it be related to?

We dropped all service limits and that didn't help us. But we notice that add more replicas delays OOM

Comment: "How does it fix? What could it be related to?"  it's related to you not having enough memory to do the operation you specified.  You can fix it by giving it all the memory it needs

Comment: we have enough memory on the service, OOM occurs when we have huge memory reserve

 
@possum how to add additional memory only to LibreOffice?

Comment: Well, it won't throw OOM for no reason. How did you monitor the memory consumption? Maybe you need to either throttle or scale out? Is there a memory leak, maybe?

Comment: @Fildor we have graphic based on Graphana that shows memory consumptions and service memory limits. OOM occurs when memory consumption is far away from limits

Maybe it is LibreOffice behavior?

Comment: That's possible. Libreoffice is not at all known for having a slim memory footprint. Maybe try out an alternative like Pandoc?

Comment: @Fildor tried pandoc, it doesn't print required images and has problem with cyrillic fonts (may be i have wrong config). Do you have another solution to convert without too much of custom config to show images and print correct text?

Comment: There are a bunch for html to pdf or direct pdf creation but for docx to pdf those would be my two go-to solutions, too.